# SQL query(or function) to find the total no. of occurance of a particular string in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, phpmyadmin

I have a big table, where one of the columns have text responses from many users (thousands of rows). I need to find the total number of occurance of a partcular word in that response column. If I use

```
SELECT count(*) from Table where Response like '%wordtobefound%'
```

it gives number of rows that contains the 'wordtobefound', but I need total number of occurances of the word 'wordtobefound' in all rows.

Note: I would prefer a user defined function that I can add to database and use again and again.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? They're very different.

Comment: you tagged as mysql and oracle.  Are you using both platforms?

Comment: If you are using Oracle, look at the REGEXP_COUNT function.  THis will do what you want - http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-12818.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(BINARY (LENGTH(field_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(field_name, "your_word", "")))/LENGTH("your_word")) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    CAST((LENGTH(Response) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Response, 'wordtobefound', ""))) / LENGTH('wordtobefound') AS UNSIGNED) AS wordCount
FROM Table
```

You can use a SUM for the total :

```
SELECT
    SUM(CAST((LENGTH(Response) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Response, 'wordtobefound', ""))) / LENGTH('wordtobefound') AS UNSIGNED)) AS wordCount
FROM Table
```